# Unstable/Inconsistent Sound Output ... Device Swapping

Tags: sound, headphones

This one is weird.

Here are the questions:

1. Has anyone encountered something similar?
2. Where do I start to try and fix the problem myself? Like what path of questions/searches?
3. What things could I try to get this so I don't have to have the settings screen open.

Prior to an update a few weeks back ... everything was fine. Then after I downloaded software update I started getting the following.

I am on a ThinkPad P52s, running Ubuntu.

I open Chrome, Spotify, anything that uses sound and I can play sound no problem. But once I plug in my headphones (https://en-de.sennheiser.com/momentum-wireless-headphones-with-mic) -- and then turn on the power... the sound transfers to the headphones... for a second... then it comes out the laptop speakers... then it goes back to the headphones... then it goes back to the laptop, and so on.

This is all fixed... if I open, and keep open the settings screen for sound. It does not matter if I swap to Digital Output or Analog Output -- problem persists. What seems to be the solving thing is have this screen open:

[image]

Other information.

I have the laptop plugged into an external monitor via HDMI -- but I have tried with it unplugged from that and the problem still exists.

I have not paired the computer with the headphones via bluetooth.

The problem does not occur upon insertion of the USB it occurs when you turn on the headphones after plugging into USB -- that may sound obvious -- but I wanted to be specific.

**System Information**

```
$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ uname -a

Linux hamildank 4.18.0-25-generic #26~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 27 07:28:31 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 148
Memory at ed148000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at ed130000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

Also here is a link to a dump of my apt history from a few weeks back:
https://gist.github.com/grok/3ca82d50bcc9075b069f2e54b9e975ab

---

More information after doing a `tail -f syslog`:

```
Jul 12 13:13:55 hamildank dbus-daemon[2722]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="Get" name=":1.5147" mask="receive" pid=6881 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=10904 peer_label="snap.code.code"
Jul 12 13:13:55 hamildank dbus-daemon[2722]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="Get" name=":1.5148" mask="receive" pid=6881 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=10906 peer_label="snap.code.code"
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank pulseaudio[4053]: W: [alsa-sink-USB Audio] alsa-util.c: Got POLLNVAL from ALSA
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank pulseaudio[4053]: W: [alsa-sink-USB Audio] alsa-util.c: Could not recover from POLLERR|POLLNVAL|POLLHUP with snd_pcm_prepare(): No such device
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank kernel: [12509.348043] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 10
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank gsd-media-keys[4265]: Unable to get default sink
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank gsd-media-keys[4265]: Unable to get default source
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank upowerd[3885]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank upowerd[3885]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank upowerd[3885]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 18
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank kdeconnectd.desktop[4327]: UdevQt: unhandled device action "unbind"
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank kdeconnectd.desktop[4327]: message repeated 2 times: [ UdevQt: unhandled device action "unbind"]
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (II) config/udev: removing device MOMENTUM M2 AEBT Consumer Control
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (**) Option "fd" "52"
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (II) event8  - MOMENTUM M2 AEBT Consumer Control: device removed
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:72
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank upowerd[3885]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.3/0003:1395:004B.0006
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank upowerd[3885]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.3
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank upowerd[3885]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank kdeconnectd.desktop[4327]: UdevQt: unhandled device action "unbind"
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank kdeconnectd.desktop[4327]: UdevQt: unhandled device action "unbind"
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank gnome-shell[3758]: clutter_input_device_get_device_type: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_INPUT_DEVICE (device)' failed
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank gnome-shell[3758]: JS ERROR: TypeError: device is null#012_init/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:619:1
Jul 12 13:13:56 hamildank kernel: [12510.097545] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank kernel: [12510.257736] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1395, idProduct=004b, bcdDevice=95.90
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank kernel: [12510.257743] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank kernel: [12510.257747] usb 1-2: Product: MOMENTUM M2 AEBT

Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank kernel: [12510.377102] input: MOMENTUM M2 AEBT as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.3/0003:1395:004B.0007/input/input30
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank kernel: [12510.377155] input: MOMENTUM M2 AEBT Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.3/0003:1395:004B.0007/input/input31
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 11: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2"
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 11 was not an MTP device
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank kernel: [12510.433762] hid-generic 0003:1395:004B.0007: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [MOMENTUM M2 AEBT] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input3
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank kdeconnectd.desktop[4327]: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank kdeconnectd.desktop[4327]: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank upowerd[3885]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank upowerd[3885]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank kdeconnectd.desktop[4327]: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank upowerd[3885]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device MOMENTUM M2 AEBT Consumer Control (/dev/input/event8)
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (**) MOMENTUM M2 AEBT Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'MOMENTUM M2 AEBT Consumer Control'
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank upowerd[3885]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.3/0003:1395:004B.0007
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank kdeconnectd.desktop[4327]: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank upowerd[3885]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.3
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank kdeconnectd.desktop[4327]: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank upowerd[3885]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event8 13:72 fd 52 paused 0
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (**) MOMENTUM M2 AEBT Consumer Control: always reports core events
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (II) event8  - MOMENTUM M2 AEBT Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (II) event8  - MOMENTUM M2 AEBT Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (II) event8  - MOMENTUM M2 AEBT Consumer Control: device removed
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.3/0003:1395:004B.0007/input/input31/event8"
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "MOMENTUM M2 AEBT Consumer Control" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (II) event8  - MOMENTUM M2 AEBT Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (II) event8  - MOMENTUM M2 AEBT Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device MOMENTUM M2 AEBT (/dev/input/event7)
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2127]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank rtkit-daemon[4054]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank rtkit-daemon[4054]: Successfully made thread 10972 of process 4053 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank rtkit-daemon[4054]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank rtkit-daemon[4054]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank rtkit-daemon[4054]: Successfully made thread 10973 of process 4053 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank rtkit-daemon[4054]: Supervising 5 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jul 12 13:13:57 hamildank gsd-media-keys[4265]: Unable to get default source
```

Comment: Have a look in `/var/log` if there's a clue on what's happening. Also find out where the logs of your desktop environment go to. If you are running X then there might be a `$HOME/.xsession-errors` that contains a clue. Also do you know which program is responsible for sound? Is it PulseAudio? Try to find out where PulseAudio puts its logs, or if you can tell it where to put them and look into those logs.

Comment: @TomášPospíšek - I added some information from the syslog.

Comment: As for what is responsible for sound... I would assume it's the default of Ubuntu. Based on the log, looks like PulseAudio // ALSA.

Comment: There's a lot of stuff in that log to google around for. Looks like different parts of your system trying to get a handle on your `MOMENTUM M2 AEBT` and not making themselves up who should be in charge.
The first two lines is apparmor denying access. You should be able to figure that out with googling.

Comment: I started googling. Found some commands about turning off armor... parts about try to stop/start Pulseaudio ... no dice. I've probably dumped a couple hours into this problem today so I am going to pause, and as I make more progress I guess I'll update this.

Comment: Best guess right now, my system is detecting my headphones as a keyboard... then going back to audio device.

Comment: Hello @SterlingHamilton I've been facing the same issue the past few months. Were you ever able to solve this ?

Comment: @ShrutheeshRaman I have not. I still encounter this problem and I have noticed it with other Bluetooth devices I think. My goto solution is just to wire in. If you find something, plesae report back :)